# Fatou's theorem

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

[image]

I don't understand how does $(77)$ follow  from $(79)$ and $(81)$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Write out the definition of $g_n$ and $g_{n+1}$. Now what do you know about infimum over a smaller set?

Comment: Probably the definition of $g_n$ is not very well-written. This is $$g_n(x)=\inf_{i \geq n} f_i(x)$$

Comment: I updated my question. Can you help? @tangentbundle

Comment: @TheSilverDoe ?

Comment: @JohnNash Think about it more than $30$ seconds. The fact that $(79)$ and $(81)$ imply $(77)$ is immediate.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I’m still thinking and I didn’t get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $g_n\leq f_n$, we have that $\int g_n d\mu\leq \int f_n d\mu$, and hence
$$
\liminf_n \int g_n d\mu \leq \liminf_n \int f_n d\mu.
$$
Since $g_n$ is an increasing sequence, so is $\int g_n d\mu$, and hence
$$
\inf_{i\geq n}\int g_i d\mu=\int g_n d\mu,
$$
which means that
$$
\liminf_n \int g_n d\mu=\lim_n \int g_n d\mu\stackrel{(81)}{=}\int f d\mu.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Because as $n$ gets larger you are taking the infimum on a smaller set.